# Reference a particular object which has already been instantiated

Tags: java, oop

I have three classes. The first class basically draws a box on screen. This class is called Box. In the second class I instantiate an object of the box class:

```
Box a = new Box();
```

In reality there will be multiple boxes, each with a different reference aside from a. In the third class how can I reference a particular object (e.g. a)?  I want to be able to reference an object which has already been instantiated but from a different class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible?

Yes.  Your `a` variable is a reference to that instance of a `Box` object.  Any operations which require a reference to such an instance can be supplied that reference.  For example, as a method parameter:

```
public void doSomethingWithABox(Box box) {
    // do something with box
}
```

And calling that method:

```
Box a = new Box();
someObject.doSomethingWithABox(a);
```

You could supply this reference as a method parameter for a particular method, as a constructor parameter for a particular object, etc.

Comment: What is someObject? To further clarify, in the box class I have a method called captureComponent. In the second class I instantiate a box object called a. In the third class I have a button with an action listener. When I press a button I want to call the method captureComponent but for box a. I have tried captureComponent(a); but I get an error. Any ideas what I need to put in the action listener? Thanks for your help

Comment: @volican: `someObject` is an instance of whatever object would need a reference to a `Box` instance.  Your question is *very* generic, so all anyone can really give is a very generic answer.  If you have *specific* code which produces a *specific* error then you might want to include that in your question.  Currently I have no idea what your code looks like.